# Create a new list, based on an existing list

Tags: python, list

I have several a list that correspond to each Colour, and I want to generate Colour Type.

```
Colour = ['Red, Yellow', 'Orange, Black', 'Blue, Green', 'Red']
```

I want to generate a list, identical to BallColour, but with the Colour type (shown below):

```
ColourType = ['Primary, Primary', 'Secondary, Unknown', 'Primary, Secondary', 'Primary']
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: What are `Primary`, `Secondary`, and `Unknown` stand for here? What are their relation to your variables?

Comment: So based on what the colour is, this is converted into a colour type. Red, yellow and blue are primary, orange and green are secondary and the rest (Black, white) are not classified, ie. Unknown

Comment: @Sam based on which list you want to create new list?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What specific technical problem did you encounter and need help with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easyist to do this with a `dict`:

```
BallColour = ['Red, Yellow', 'Orange, Black', 'Blue, Green', 'Red']

c_key = dict(
    Red = 'Primary',
    Blue = 'Primary',
    Yellow = 'Primary',
    Green = 'Secondary',
    Orange = 'Secondary',
    Purple = 'Secondary',
)

ColourType = []
for colors in BallColour:
    colors = colors.split(', ')
    temp = []
    for color in colors:
        if color in c_key:
            temp.append(c_key[color])
        else:
            temp.append('Unknown')
    ColourType.append(', '.join(temp))

print(ColourType)
```

[example in python tutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=BallColour%20%3D%20%5B'Red,%20Yellow',%20'Orange,%20Black',%20'Blue,%20Green',%20'Red'%5D%0A%0Ac_key%20%3D%20dict%28%0A%20%20%20%20Red%20%3D%20'Primary',%0A%20%20%20%20Blue%20%3D%20'Primary',%0A%20%20%20%20Yellow%20%3D%20'Primary',%0A%20%20%20%20Green%20%3D%20'Secondary',%0A%20%20%20%20Orange%20%3D%20'Secondary',%0A%20%20%20%20Purple%20%3D%20'Secondary',%0A%29%0A%0AColourType%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0Afor%20colors%20in%20BallColour%3A%0A%20%20%20%20colors%20%3D%20colors.split%28',%20'%29%0A%20%20%20%20temp%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0A%20%20%20%20for%20color%20in%20colors%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20color%20in%20c_key%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20temp.append%28c_key%5Bcolor%5D%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20else%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20temp.append%28'Unknown'%29%0A%20%20%20%20ColourType.append%28',%20'.join%28temp%29%29%0A%0Aprint%28ColourType%29&cumulative=true&curInstr=9&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=py3anaconda&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)